# How to create a sequence in oracle from top to bottom

Tags: sql, oracle, insert

So I have two tables in Oracle. Table A is the master table and Table B is data retrieved from a contractor. They both have the same general structure. In the end, I would like to `INSERT INTO TABLE A(SELECT * FROM TABLE B)`. However the primary key column in Table B does not exist. How do you suggest creating a primary key that at the same time generates a sequence from 4328 and on for every row in Table B?

I proceeded to do the following:

```
create sequence myseq
  increment by 1
  start with 4328
  MAXVALUE 99999
  NOCACHE
  NOCYCLE;
```

Then created a PK column to finally implemented the following:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE B (PK) VALUES(MYSEQ.nextVal);
```

But no results yielded except putting in one row at the very end. I want every row to be populated starting at 4328 and ending 291 rows later.

Comment: Well, yes, your insert will create one row.  You need to write a pl/sql script to loop and perform multiple inserts.

Comment: Anyway around that? I am using SQL Developer.

Comment: Are you inserting new rows, or updating the new PK column for existing rows?

Comment: There is no dependency on sql developer.

Comment: updating the new PK column for existing rows.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but I don't know if I undestand your problem.
Do you want to insert one row in Table A and Table B with equal PK value?
You can do it by procedure put the sequence value in a variable before insert the rows, for example:

```
BEGIN
    SELECT MYSEQ.nextval INTO v_SEQUENCE FROM dual;
    insert into table_A values (v_SEQUENCE,1,2,3);
    insert into table_B values (v_SEQUENCE,1,2,3);
END;
```

If you can get all rows from Table_B and insert into table_A with a PK you can do for example:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_A (SELECT MYSEQ.nextval, B.* FROM TABLE_B B)
```

Is it?

Comment: I want Table B to continue the PK sequence from Table A, so it would be seamless when i import all my data from table B to table A.

Comment: @user40720 - if you want it to be seamless when you copy data from B to A, why don't you generate the key as you do the insert, rather than in advance? What happens if new rows are inserted in A in the meantime? And how does A get *its* PK value?

Comment: How would i generate it on the fly?

Comment: is it? INSERT INTO TABLE_A (SELECT rownum, B.* FROM TABLE_B B)

Comment: when inserting from table b to a, i get the following error message: SQL Error: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected DATE got NUMBER
00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"

Answer (score 0):

Your approach only calls the sequence once.  What you want to do is perform a loop in PL/SQL to call the sequence as many times as needed:

```
BEGIN
  FOR x IN 1 .. 291 LOOP
    INSERT INTO TABLE B (PK) VALUES(MYSEQ.nextVal);
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Make sure you drop and recreate your sequence to ensure it starts at the right value.